# Securing a webapp with nginx, modSecurity and pfsense

Tags: security, nginx, home-server, pfsense, web-application

As a hobby project, I started a website on my PC. I built it with nginx and everything worked fine.
Now, trying to secure it, things get complicated.

Im trying to setup a firewall/waf physically on another machine (an oldish macbook pro) to sit in front of the web server, in order to reduce server load and have a better monitoring capabilities on the security side.

what Im struggling with is how does it all go together, if at all?
I cant find anywhere docs on how to go about making it all work together ..

Do do I put pfsense and then nginx? or the other way around?
what's the best practice here?
It feels like Im completely missing something here..

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing is, after acquiring two NIC is as follows:
0: Install Ubuntu as an OS
1: Setting up pfsense on a VM that has one actual NIC on WAN and the second virtual one on LAN
2: Setting up a virtual NIC on Ubuntu to connect with the pfsense LAN
3: Hook the nginx to that NIC
4: Install ModSecurity on nginx
5: Setup the Ubuntu to act as a router on the actual second NIC with dhcp server (setup as dhcp, setup port forwarding)